# Download entire directory in a bucket of MinIO

Tags: python, minio

Here is my MinIO tree

```
bucket1
|
|-dir1
|-dir2
    |-file1
    |-file2
    |-file3
```

I want to download the entire directory "`dir2`" using python API.

The only way I can think of is to download files one by one. Is there another way / API call to download entire directory?

Answer (score 5):

If you simply need to download the files use minio client copy.
mc cp (source) (destination) --recursive

Comment: OP states "using python API"?

Comment: I find this simpler than using the API.

Answer (score 3):

if u are using api lookelike python u can use this:

```
client = Minio(
    "storage_address",
    access_key="XXXXXXXXXXX",
    secret_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
)

for bucket in client.list_buckets():
    for item in client.list_objects(bucket.name,recursive=True):
        client.fget_object(bucket.name,item.object_name,item.object_name)
```

`recursive=True` will open all folders and `fget_object` will save file with file name and folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible right now. The closest approach is to use the `ComposeObject` function just like on the [Golang SDK API Reference](https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference.html#ComposeObject).
However, it is not clear that the file extension will be an archive just like ZIP or not. The most possible approach is to download the files one by one.